# How to standard scale a large numpy matrix with sklearn? (batch processing)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am working in a classification problem with gradient boosting. As usual before classifiying I would like to scale my feature matrix (`878049, 3208`).

```
A = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(training_data['col1'].values.reshape(-1, 1).ravel())
B = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(training_data['col2'].values.reshape(-1, 1).ravel())
C = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(training_data['col3'].values.reshape(-1, 1).ravel())
```

Then:

```
A_1 = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(A.reshape(-1, 1)).A
B_2 = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(B.reshape(-1, 1)).A
C_3 = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(C.reshape(-1, 1)).A
D_4 = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(training_data['Col_4'].values)
```

Then:

```
print(A_1.shape, B_2.shape, C_3.shape, D_4.shape)
>>> (878049, 10) (878049, 2249) (878049, 7) (878049, 942)


X =  np.column_stack((A_1.A, B_2, C_3, D_4))
```

Here is when everything freeze:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_new = scaler.partial_fit(X)
```

However, although I tried to `partial_fit()` function, my whole computer freeze. Thus, what can I do in a situation like this?.

I also tried to scale each feature before sticking the arrays. Nevertheless, I belive that actually wrong. Any suggestion guys?.

**update**
I also tried to feature select before scaling. However, I believe it is wrong.

Comment: It seems you are using partial_fit wrongly. Show us the relevant code. There should be no problem at all regarding this operation on this data-size. (If it's a good thing to do in your use-case is another question)

Comment: I updated the question with more details @sascha, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.partial_fit) of `partial_fit` explain what's happening. The following is the relevant part:

> partial_fit(X, y=None)
>
> All of X is processed as a single batch

So it's **your task to call partial_fit multiple times with partial-data** (as opposed to call it one-time with all your data like you are doing).

Just try something like this (untested code; just to give you the idea):

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

n = X.shape[0]  # number of rows
batch_size = 1000  # number of rows in each call to partial_fit
index = 0  # helper-var

while index < n:
    partial_size = min(batch_size, n - index)  # needed because last loop is possibly incomplete
    partial_x = X[index:index+partial_size]
    scaler.partial_fit(partial_x)
    index += partial_size
```

#### Remarks

- `partial_fit` returns `None` (which is also wrongly used in your code)
- after using `partial_fit` within the loop, you can use `scaler.transform` to get your rescaled data: *maybe you need to this within a loop too*

Comment: Thanks for the support. After all where is the final matrix that I will fit with the gradient boosting machine?.

Comment: After you trained your ```scaler```, ```final_matrix = scaler.transform(X)``` (if you got enough memory; should not be much; with more complicated stuff like PCA, you would need to loop here too). Keep in mind, that most people don't standardize data when using tree-based approaches like your GBM.

Comment: I just added `final_matrix = scaler.transform(X) ` just below `index += partial_size`, and again my computer just freeze, any idea of what to do?. Is it only recommended to scale the data for linear models like svms and linear regression?.

Comment: My jupyter kernel still crashes and automatically restarts after transforming `X`. Any idea of how to proceed?.

Comment: As i indicated: it's possible that you got not enough memory to use transform on the whole batch. So just transform in mini-batches, like we did while training the scaler! (I'm not exactly sure what's happening inside transform: e.g. if it needs a whole temp-array of same size. If that's the case and i don't think it's worse, it looks like the data in memory occupies more than 50% of your available system memory). **Another remark:** If memory is really the factor here, your chances of using GBM after transforming are not good (should use up much more memory!!!)

Comment: **Something else:** i hope you didn't use transform **inside** the while-loop. This would mean that you didn't understand the code at all, which is hopefully not the case. But your comment ```I just added final_matrix = scaler.transform(X) just below index += partial_size, and again my computer just freeze``` is not that precise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you provide an example of how to fit by mini batches assuming the above mentioned conditions?. I believe that this topic needs more examples, since in the documentation I did not found how to work with large datasets.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, really: but this is beginner-stuff (and i won't post more code). In general you do the same like before, but using transform instead of fit. You have to think about the inputs and outputs of the functions (fit only took input; but transform also returns something). It might be possible, that you are so tight on memory that you need to overwrite **in-place**. It also seems, you are lacking some basics and memory-constrained ml-topics are not the wisest choice to learn these basics. The above ideas are not much about scikit-learn, but about general programming.

Comment: I also have questions regarding while "while moving data from A to B" do I carryout bias?.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: While I do a minibatch I rescale just a portion of the data, is it correct just to rescale that portion of the data without considering the other chunk of data?... I am carrying out some sort of bias?

Comment: Of course it's valid, because we fitted/learned the scaling-parameters in the step before (we already saw each sample). These parameters are then part of the scaler-object and will be used with each transform. There is also no dependency between the samples regarding scaling, because all we do is calculating a function f(x):y (where x,y might be multidimensional = features)

Comment: @sascha. Thank you! How we can apply same thing on panda dataframe and then assign back the scaled values to the dataframe after scalign please?