# Is it possible to fit() a scikit-learn model in a loop or with an iterator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Usually people use `scikit-learn` to train a model this way:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier as gbc
clf = gbc()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

It works fine as long as users' memory is large enough to accommodate the entire dataset. The dilemma for me is exactly this--the dataset is too big for my memory. My current solution is to enlarge the virtual memory of my machine and I have already made the system extremely slow by having too much virtual memory--so I start to think whether or not is it possible to feed the `fit()` method with samples in batches like this (**and the answre is no, please keep reading and stop reminding me that the answer is no**):

```
clf = gbc()
for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):
    clf.fit(X_train[i], y_train[i])
```

so that I can read the training set from hard drive only when needed. I read the [sklearn's manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#refitting-and-updating-parameters) and it seems to me that it does not support this:

```
Calling fit() more than once will overwrite what was learned by any previous fit()
```

So, is this possible?

Comment: I think you would need to create a separate instance of the LinearRegression class for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @njp emmm? My understanding is that, say I create multiple LinearRegression instances, I will be training a few separate models using one sample only...which is *not* what I want ..

Comment: What you have proposed doesn't work. It simply fits a new model (with different coefficients) at each iteration

Comment: Are you having problems with loading the full dataset into memory, or it is stuck during the fit?

Comment: @StupidWolf you are right--as shown on the official manual as well as my quote, the code I proposed wont work. So the question is about is it possible for me to make it work.

Comment: @StupidWolf 
`Are you having problems with loading the full dataset into memory, or it is stuck during the fit?` this actually depends on a few factors, such as the preprocessing I have to do, the virtual memory I set (it is a trade-off between dataset size and training speed, we cant wait for a month just for one training anyway). For the current project I am doing--we are using synesthetic data so we can make the dataset really big if the memory can accommodate them.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. It seems to me that what you are proposing couldn't work, even if scikit-learn could do what you propose. The reason is that even the estimators depend on interactions between each data point, through the XtX and Xty matrices, so you can't update estimates of the parameters (and everything else calculated by the linear regression) with blocks of data.

Comment: Maybe a different regression model is called for? I don't know if it's possible but I'm envisaging some kind of Bayesian regression where each block of data creates a posterior distribution, which is then used as a prior distribution when the next block of data is processed.

Comment: Maybe you could try to improve memory usage instead, such as changing the column data type?

Comment: @Ming well first I would say that these are two aspects I can try and optimizing memory usage is beyond the scope of this question. But for the particular problem I am solving, I think optimizing memory won't solve the issue. As I said in the previous comment, this time we are using synthetic data so if we can a lot more rows if our machine has bigger memory--this is true with or without memory optimization techniques. Regarding the datatype you ask--they are all float.

Comment: There are a few types of `float`s in Pandas you can choose - if you're willing to sacrifice precision in your dataset. If you wish to do incremental learning with linear regression, which sklearn is not supported, you can write your own algorithm like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79845 . Or use your own method to approximate the optimum of the linear equation coefficients, by looping each batch of data repeatedly until convergence like training a neural network.

Comment: @Ming sure but as I said memory usage optimization is NOT the concern of this question...and even if I can change float64 to float16 (which is extremely aggressive already), I only get 4x more data...but say I can feed my dataset in batches, I can easily accommodate 10x, 100x more data to my model. And LinearRegression is just an example here...given scikit-learn has so many models, I think it is too costly for me to manually implement the models I am currently using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the section [6. Strategies to scale computationally: bigger data](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html) of the official manual mentioned by @StupidWolf in this post, I am aware that this question is more to this than meets the eye.

The real difficulty is about the design of a lot of models.

Take Random Forest as an example, one of the most important techniques used to improve its performance compared with the simpler Decision Tree is the application of [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#Bagging), which means that the algorithm has to pick some random samples from the entire dataset to construct several weak learners as the basis of the Random Forest. It means that feeding the model with one sample after another won't work with this design.

Although it is still possible for `scikit-learn` to define an interface for end-users to implement so that `scikit-learn` can pick a random sample by calling this interface and end-users will decide how their implementation of the interface is about to return the needed data by scanning the dataset on the hard drive, it becomes way more complicated than I initially thought and the performance gain may not be very significant given that the IO-heavy "full table scan" (in database's term) is frequently needed.

Answer (score 3):

This do not work in scikit-learn as explained in the comment section as well as in the documentation. However you can use [river](https://riverml.xyz/latest/) ( which is a python package for online/streaming machine learning). This package should be well-suited for you problematic.

Below is an example of training a LinearRegression using river.

```
from river import datasets
from river import linear_model
from river import metrics
from river import preprocessing

dataset = datasets.TrumpApproval()

model = (
    preprocessing.StandardScaler() |
    linear_model.LinearRegression(intercept_lr=.1)
)
metric = metrics.MAE()

for x, y, in dataset:
    y_pred = model.predict_one(x)

    # Update the running metric with the prediction and ground truth value
    metric.update(y, y_pred)

    # Train the model with the new sample
    model.learn_one(x, y)
```

Comment: thanks for  the proposal but I would like to keep `scikit-learn` since this is also the library used by other co-workers...switching to a new framework is a bit too drastic at this stage for me...

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear in your question is which steps in the machine learning are slow for you. As also noted in the manual for [riverml](https://riverml.xyz/latest/user-guide/mini-batching/) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538376/how-to-standard-scale-a-large-numpy-matrix-with-sklearn-batch-processing) in sklearn there is an option to do a partial fit. You will be restricted in terms of the models you can use for this [incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning).

So using your example lets say we use a [stochastic gradient descent classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X,y = make_classification(100000)
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
all_classes  = list(set(y))

for ix in np.split(np.arange(0,X.shape[0]),100):
    clf.partial_fit(X[ix,:],y[ix],classes = all_classes)
```

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf, I think the incremental learning link is the thing I am looking for--although it explicitly says that only a limited subset of models have this feature...Regarding the "slow" part...well this is beyond the scope of this question so perhaps I should revise my original statement to avoid the term "slow" but instead I would say "the program is already using a lot of virtual memory, usually more than twice of the physical one so I would also explore other possibilities which allow me to have a larger dataset"